# Safe persistent data file for bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script which needs to store/read a small dataset (less than 10 attributes) in a file. The obvious solutions would be to implement this as bash, and sourcing it from the runtime script, however there will be a lot of these datafiles scattered around a large shared filesystem - I want to prevent other people injecting code into the file (I don't mind if they change the data).

Is there a way to process a set of assignments from a script without executing any other commands? Is there a better way to achieve the end result?

Comment: use a config file parser, do it yourself with grep/sed/awk/getopts/... or use existing parsers for ini/json/xml/csv/...